# Setup p5.js in Electron

Tags: javascript, graphics, electron, p5.js

I am trying to use **p5.js** in a **electron desktop app**. I tried using **templates from github** but it didn't work I tried **setting up my self** it didn't work either.

Here is my ***index.html*** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="p5.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my ***index.js*** code:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

app.on('ready', () => {
    let window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true,
        },
    })
    window.loadFile('index.html');
})
```

Comment: "didn't work" is too unspecific. What is not working?

Comment: I start the app and there is nothing there. I use createCanvas method to create a canvas in setup function, than I write background(0) but when I open the app there is no black area in my screen, I don't know why

Comment: Time to debug! Open devTools and see if there are errors: [Application Debugging](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging)

Comment: There are a [lot of templates](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/wiki/State-of-Electron-frameworks-%5BMay-2021%5D) you can start with if you want something pre-started.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just copy the index.html from p5.js itself, cause rn it doesn't seem as though you're referencing the actual library anywhere in either of those files.
this should be all the html you'd need:

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

and:

```
<body>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
```